# Is it possible to export Visual Studio UML diagrams to Enterprise Architect?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml, enterprise-architect

Working with Visual Studio 2010 and having all the UML diagrams in the VS solution, I wonder if it is possible to export those diagrams (classes, workflows) in Enterprise Architect to benefit of its tools.

In brief, I would like to define in Enterprise Architect test scenarios for all these classes and workflows but I would like not to recreate them all manually.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: Nothing? Nobody gives any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, the tool is available here: [MSDN subscribers download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff655021.aspx)

Comment: this link is broken, is there a tool name you can mention here?

Answer (score 0):

This online service http://modeling-languages.com/content/xmi2-tool-exchanging-uml-models-among-case-tools helps to exchange UML class diagrams between different tools. Not sure if the XMI format imported/exported by your specific tool combination is similar to one of the currently supported tools